# Issues with Spring boot demo project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I recently started learning spring boot for java, and found a demo project here: https://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/file-upload-angularjs-spring-boot-rest which I tried to implement. The "demo" doesn't really go in depth so I just tried remaking the project in intellij using the code he has. I'm currently running into an issue in the DocumentServiceImpl.java file:

```
package com.formupload.demo.service;

import com.formupload.demo.dao.DocumentDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class DocumentServiceImpl implements DocumentService {

    @Autowired
    private DocumentDao documentDao;


    @Override
    public ResponseMetadata save(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.setDocName(file.getOriginalFilename());
        doc.setFile(file.getBytes());
        documentDao.save(doc);
        ResponseMetadata metadata = new ResponseMetadata();
        metadata.setMessage("success");
        metadata.setStatus(200);
        return metadata;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getDocumentFile(Long id) {
        return documentDao.findById(id).getFile();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Document> findAll() {
        return (List<Document>) documentDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

the part that is giving me trouble is the line: return documentDao.findbyId(id).getFile(); intellij is telling me it can't find the method getFile(). I'm not sure what I did wrong as the only thing I changed was instead of using findOne() on that same line I used findById().

Here is the documentDao.java code:

```
package com.formupload.demo.dao;

import com.formupload.demo.service.Document;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface DocumentDao extends CrudRepository<Document, Long> {

}
```

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Document.java code as well:

package com.formupload.demo.service;

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Document {

    private long id;

    @Column
    private String docName;

    @Column
    @Lob
    private byte[] file;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDocName() {
        return docName;
    }

    public void setDocName(String docName) {
        this.docName = docName;
    }

    public void setFile(byte[] file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public byte[] getFile() {
        return file;
    }

}
```

Comment: You missed the annotation `@Service` in `DocumentServiceImpl`

Comment: @NicholasK thanks for letting me know, unfortunately that didn't fix my other issue.

Comment: [`findById`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-) returns an [`Optional<Document>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), not a `Document`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`findById`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#findById-ID-) returns an [`Optional<Document>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), not a `Document`.

Your code should be:

```
@Override
public byte[] getDocumentFile(Long id) {
    return documentDao.findById(id)
                      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Document not found: " + id))
                      .getFile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error on the line:

```
return documentDao.findbyId(id).getFile();
```

saying that the `getFile()` method cannot be found, then it is likely that your `Document` class does not have a method with the signature `getFile()`. In the tutorial you are following, there is a comment in the Document class saying:

```
    //getters and setters goes here
```

So you should make sure that you added the getters and setters as needed, like so:

```
public byte[] getFile() {
    return file;
}
```

Comment: I just added the Document.java code, I did have a getFile() method in it.

Comment: As [@Andreas commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280522/issues-with-spring-boot-demo-project/52280590?noredirect=1#comment91509133_52280522), the `findById` returns an `Optional<Document>` which must be checked for a value and then unwrapped before calling `getFile()``.

Answer (score 0):

FindById Not defined in CrudRepository Of the Spring-data version you are using.

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-commons/1.13.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html

if you need it, you should add findById inside your DocumentDao :

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentDao extends CrudRepository<Document, Long>{
    Document findById(Long aLong);
}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
documentDao.findById(id).getFile();
```

if you upgrade to 2.0.10.RELEASE you could use findById by default as it's part of CrudRepository definition.

see: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-944 , findOne also removed in version 2 as part of this commit.